# I am looking for a database of US aircraft casting numbers

Tags: united-states, aircraft

I have found many US aircraft have casting numbers in their aluminum parts, bosses, tools, to identify the specific aicraft.  28 is a PBY, I believe. Is there a book or database on these, and when this all started?

Comment: Available to the manufacturers and the companies who do the casting of the items... Will they make it publicly available hmm...

Comment: I'm not aware of an official list, but Aviation Archaeological Investigation and Research (AAIR) have a page where they have collected a list of [Part Number Prefix by Aircraft Type](https://www.aviationarchaeology.com/src/partaircraft.htm) for  US military aircraft.  And yes, `28-` (rather than just `28`) is the prefix for the PBY